# Contradiction in the derivative of the unit step function being the dirac delta function

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

We know that $\delta(t)=\frac{d}{dt}u_c(t)$, where $u_c(t)$ is the unit step function. However, using this to find the Laplace transform of $\delta(t)$, $$\int_0^\infty{\delta(t)e^{-st}dt}=\int_0^\infty{\delta(t)dt}$$ $$=\int_0^\infty{\frac{d}{dt}u_c(t)dt}=u_c(\infty)-u_c(0)$$ But, $u_c(t)=1$ at $t\ge0$ so $u_c(\infty)-u_c(0)=1-1=0$. Isn't this contradictory to the Laplace transform of $\delta(t)$ being equal to $1$?

Comment: Convention in the Laplace transform is to take the integral starting at "$0-$", which means just below zero. Otherwise, you have problems ($\delta$ is defined so that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, dx = f(0)$, which does not tell you what to do with $\int_0^{\infty}$ without some modification so that $0$ lies in the interior of the interval of integration, for example). Doing this removes the problem, since $u_c(0-)=0$.

Comment: To be more general than Chapper's comment, $\delta(t)$ is not an ordinary function, but rules such as the FTC are proved for only for ordinary functions satisfying certain conditions. $u_c$ does not satify those conditions. You cannot naively assume that normal integration rules always apply to generalized functions. You have to tread very carefully, examing the definitions at every step.